# Fancybox different appearance

Tags: jquery, fancybox, position, wrapper

Please look at the link below and click on each item.
http://seerman.ir/index.php?page=products&cat=tableau&sid=43
 Once you are clicking on a new thumbnail, Fancybox works well until it wants to show the picture. While appearing picture, the wrapper box move to bottom. But when you want to see the same item again after click on it, everything appears correctly.
How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to fix some things on your site :

1). use a single instance of jQuery. Currently you are loading version 1.8.0 and 1.7.0

2). You have several duplicated IDs when they should be unique within the same page so change you links from this

```
<a id="example1" href=pages/details.php?cat=tableau&id=35&code=1123>...
```

into this

```
<a class="example1" href="pages/details.php?cat=tableau&id=35&code=1123">...
```

**Notice** that I also added the missing quotes to the `href=" "`

3). fancybox doesn't know that you are opening images because the format of your link (`href`) so it calculates the position of the box from the initial content and then renders the image from that position so change this

```
j("a#example1").fancybox();
```

into this

```
j("a.example1").fancybox({
    type: "image",
    onComplete: function () {
        var repos = setTimeout(function () {
            $.fancybox.center();
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

Check **[FAQs](http://fancybox.net/faq)** No.6 for further information.

**Notice** I changed the selector's prefix from `#` into `.` because we are now using *classes*

**EDIT** : since your php file is returning some data before the image, the fancybox top position is calculated based on data. You may want to run the `$.fancybox.center()` method after the image has been shown. Give it some seconds to load using settimeout

Comment: Thank you dear @JFK. I think the most important thing that I had to do was `type: "image"`. I applied this code, but the problem did not solved.

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi : you may need to apply the `$.fancybox.center()` method since your php file returns previous data before the image. See my edited answer.